# Create a formula that creates a curve between two points

Tags: curves

We have two points, $A$ and $B$. The difference in $x$ is 1 unit, and the difference in $y$ is arbitrary. For each point we also know the gradient. First, I want to draw a smooth line that connects both points *and* smoothly transitions between gradients. Then, I want a function that returns a $y$-value for any value of $x$ between $A$ and $B$, where $0 < x < 1$.

Comment: By gradient do you mean a colour?

Comment: What do you mean by "smoothly transition" between gradients. There is lots of ways to do this and your definition of "smoothly" will affect what method you use.

Comment: by gradient I mean rise/run of the tangent at that point. By "smoothly transition" I mean that the gradient changes in as a function of x.

Comment: So you want $f'(x)$ continuous at the change. Do you also want other derivatives continuous at the change (for" smoothness")?

Comment: I think Adriano has more or less nailed it. He wrongly assumes that f(0)=0, but I was able to work around that by adding and subtracting 'ya'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that our conditions are:
$$
f(0) = 0,~~ f(1) = b,~~ f'(0) = p,~~ f'(1) = q
$$
and that we use a cubic polynomial $f(x) = a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$. Solving this system of equations yields:
$$
f(x) = (p + q - 2b)x^3 + (3b - 2p - q)x^2 + px
$$

---

For example, if our first point is $(0, 0)$ with a gradient of $p = 3$ and our second point is $(1, 4)$ with a gradient of $q = -2$, then our curve is:
$$
f(x) = -7x^3 + 8x^2 + 3x
$$
Indeed, the plot looks like:

[image]

Comment: what plotting software are you using to produce the images in your answer?

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+-7x%5E3+%2B+8x%5E2+%2B+3x+for+x+%3D+0..1

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 conditions: $f(x_a)=y_a$, $f(x_b)=y_b$, $f'(x_a)=m_a$ and $f'(x_b)=m_b$. As such you need a cubic equation - $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$.

This is known as a [cubic spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation). There are other types of splines which may be more suitable for your application but will involve harder mathematics.

You should be able to find lots with a simple google search.

Answer (score 0):

#### The curve

> $$f(x) = (p + q - 2b) (x / k) ^ 3 + (3b - 2p - q) (x / k) ^2 + p (x / k) + m$$

The first point is *(0 , m)* and the second is *(k , (m + b))*

---

#### First and second point:

> $$f(0) = m$$
> $$and$$
> $$f(k) = m + b$$

---

#### The gradient of the first and second point:

> $$f'(0) = p / k$$
> $$and$$
> $$f'(k) = q / k$$

---

#### The *y* value in the middel:

> $$f(k / 2) = (p - q + 4 (b + m)) / 4$$

---

#### The tangent in the middel:

> $$f(k / 2) = 3xb / 2k - x (p + q) / 4k + (p - b + 4m) / 4$$